# Dans quelles situations utilise-t-on « messieurs-dames » ?

Tags: usage, régionalismes, oral, salutations

J'ai entendu dire qu'on devrait utiliser la phrase « Bonjour messieurs-dames » quand on entre dans un magasin pour saluer les personnes à l'intérieur, mais est-ce que c'est très utilisé ou plutôt rarement ? Est-ce que c'est très formel ou utilisé seulement dans certaines régions ?

Comment: Tu dois faire une inversion complète: « Messieurs-dames bonjour ». Galanterie oblige…

Comment: @Knu la galanterie ? quel rapport ici ? Les messieurs sont, malgré l'inversion, toujours en première position...

Comment: Et pour saluer un·e couple, dit-on aussi "Bonjour Messieurs-Dames" ? (encore entendu ce matin, en entrant dans une boutique de chocolat Yves Thuriès, de la part du vendeur, pour saluer ma femme et moi).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

L'expression « messieurs-dames » est très fréquemment utilisée. Elle est plutôt informelle tout en étant courtoise. 
Son équivalent formel est « Mesdames, mesdemoiselles, messieurs, bonjour [ou bienvenue, etc.] ». C'est par ces mots que commencent souvent les discours politiques ou encore certaines émissions télévisées.

Il existe également une version d'un formalisme intermédiaire : « Bonjour à toutes et à tous ». Cette forme s'utilise lorsque l'on anime une réunion, par exemple. On l'entend parfois à la télévision également.

Quant à l'aspect régional, j'entends l'expression « messieurs-dames » un peu partout en France, mais je ne sais si elle est utilisée en Belgique, en Suisse, au Québec ou dans les pays d'Afrique francophone.

Comment: Je l'entend parfois au Québec.

Comment: L'omission de *Bonjour/Bonsoir* dans la formule est très fréquente, c'est juste. Un simple *Messieurs dames* est, il me semble, encore plus fréquent que les deux variantes *Bonjour Messieurs dames* et *Messieurs dames bonjour*. Dans le nord-est français, c'est le cas. A comparer avec d'autres régions du monde bien entendu.

Comment: Au Québec, l'expression semble plus formelle. On ne l'entendra pas d'une personne que l'on croise à la porte d'un centre commercial. Généralement réservé pour les discours et les situations nécessitant une marque de salutation distinctive (dans le sens de plus polie).

Comment: Voire les commentaires ci-dessous sur l'aspect vulgaire de cette expression.

Answer (score 9):

Il est vrai que dans son [dictionnaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/monsieur), l'*Académie française* inscrive que « [l]a formule *Messieurs dames !* n'est pas [correct](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/correct)e. ». On note qu'on a omis le trait d'union et qu'on n'a pas choisi de dire que c'était *incorrect*. [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/monsieur/52460/locution) identifie la même formule comme familière. Au [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/messieurs-dames), on relève la formule avec le trait d'union dans une remarque ; on donne des exemples comme Arland, [*Ordre*](https://books.google.com/books?id=kic-AAAAIAAJ&dq=%28Arland%2C%20Ordre&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22messieurs-dames%22) (1929), et Fargue, [*Le piéton Paris*](https://books.google.com/books?id=G3AnAQAAMAAJ&q=Je%20viens%20voir%20si%20ces%20messieurs-dames%20ressemblent%20bien%20aux%20portraits&dq=Je%20viens%20voir%20si%20ces%20messieurs-dames%20ressemblent%20bien%20aux%20portraits&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOmsTA5qfPAhWB7IMKHWr-CIAQ6AEILTAC) (1939). Au *LBU14* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, 14<sup>e</sup>, §576) on aborde avec discernement d'abord l'expression « Messieurs, dames » en contexte de répétition du déterminant avec la coordination : on dit qu'elle « appartient à une langue peu distinguée, voire peu polie », et non qu'il s'agisse d'une infamie, puis on rappelle qu'on dit dans l'usage distingué *Mesdames, Messieurs*. Ensuite on distingue *ces messieurs-dames*, avec le déterminant, disant qu'il « s'emploie éventuellement avec des intentions de dénigrement » et on cite Georges Pompidou : « [...] Puisque ces messieurs-dames viennent là en tant que militants, eh bien il est normal que nous les considérions comme des militants. ». C'est qu'on peut vouloir dire ou faire dire autres choses que ce qu'on nous a appris à répéter.

---

C'est [utilisé](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=messieurs-dames%2Cmessieurs%20dames%2Cmesdames%20messieurs%2Cmadame%20monsieur%2Cm%27sieurs%20dames%2Cm%27sieurs-dames&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmessieurs%20-%20dames%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmessieurs%20-%20dames%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMessieurs%20-%20Dames%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMessieurs%20-%20dames%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmessieurs%20dames%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmessieurs%20dames%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMessieurs%20Dames%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMessieurs%20dames%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmesdames%20messieurs%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMesdames%20Messieurs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmesdames%20messieurs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMesdames%20messieurs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMadame%20Monsieur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cm%27sieurs%20dames%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cm%27sieurs%20-%20dames%3B%2Cc0) et selon la source ce peut être « pas correct », « familier », « peu distingué voire peu poli » et donc c'est plutôt le contraire de « formel » ; mais ce peut être naturel pour les uns, et utilisé à bon escient par d'autres.

Personnellement comme salutation à l'oral dans une situation comme le petit commerce que l'on fréquente régulièrement, je préfère « bonjour ! (comment allez-vous/ça va ?) » tout simplement (j'utilise aussi parfois *bien le bonjour !* avec le *merci bien !* dans un tel contexte) ; autrement l'idée de saluer un groupe dans un magasin m'apparaîtrait tout aussi artificielle et inusitée que celle de systématiquement m'exprimer comme l'appel d'une lettre dans la vie de tous les jours. Je ne traite pas du contexte de l'allocution ou protocolaire, ni de celui du milieu de travail traditionnel, qu'on ne mentionne pas en question.

Answer (score 6):

C'est une formule classique pour s'adresser une assemblée qui se compose d'hommes et de femmes.

C'est une version moins formelle que

> Mesdames, Messieurs, …

et elle n'est utilisée que pour les performances orales (discours, salutations, …). À l'écrit, on se contentera de la version formelle.

Comment: Je l'utiliserais uniquement dans un contexte informel, pas dans un discours.

Comment: @Unfrancophone tout dépendra du discours.

Comment: Je ne l'utiliserais pas, ça sent l'alcool, comme expliqué par cl-r.

Answer (score 2):

Ne pas résister à la francophonie des bistrots!
Attribuée à Alphonse BOUDARD, cette façon de saluer, avec l'accent traînard façon argot des comptoirs parigots :

> Bonjour m'sieurs-dames,... et excusez-moi si je m'trompe.

Évidemment, cela date un peu.
A n'utiliser que si l'on a la fraise (le nez tuméfié par le gros rouge qui tache), le béret, et l'habitude du rade (café où l'on jette l'ancre au moins une fois par jour pour s'en jeter un derrière la cravate, après avoir sommé de garçon de servir ".. pas plus haut qu'le bord"), cela se termine en levant le verre par un "Santé" et souvent un cul-sec.

Comment: Encore en usage pour la quête dans le métro, j'vai maint'nant passer parmi vous m'sieurs-dames.

Comment: On peut aussi carrément enlever le bonjour, ou le placer après m'sieurs-dames. Il n'y a pas de s à moi. Et ce serait plutôt 'si je m'trompe' ou 'si j'me trompe' :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier — Bien lu pour *moi*, mais pas d’accord sur la place de «’» : il n’est pas sur le *e* du *je* mais sur celui de *m*. ***Je*** est la personne la plus importante au monde et le seul mot qui nous reste quand on parle de nous-même, à moins que l’on s’appelle Alain Delon (qui parle de lui à la troisième personne [du Singulier]) !

Comment: C'est discutable bien sûr, mais "j'me" est largement utilisé dans le langage courant, y compris par moi; bon, c'est vrai je ne suis pas Alain Delon :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier — C’est plus la référence à Boudard et les circonstances (s’affirmer devant un auditoire) qui  me font entendre ce *je* en première place, comme un « C’est *moi* » vindicatif, alors que le *j’me* est plus une simple appropriation de la conversation… voilà pour alimenter la jactance quand on s’accoude dans un rade en disant «  Bonjour m’sieu… »

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai jamais utilisé cette expression car elle est très laide.
Quand je rentre dans un endroit où il y a plusieurs personnes hommes et femmes, je dis "bonjour Mesdames, bonjour Messieurs".
C'est ainsi que l'on m'a appris à le faire dans le milieu dans lequel j'ai été éduquée et qui était un milieu "puriste de la langue française".
Donc, si vous voulez vous exprimer avec raffinement, n'utilisez jamais l'expression "messieurs-dames".

Comment: On peut aussi dire en regardant les femmes du 'public' sur un ton respectueux, "Mesdames", après un court silence et un déplacement du regard vers les hommes, "Messieurs" puis se mêler à l'assemblée ainsi saluée, ou rejoindre des amis.

Comment: Il semble donc possible d'être hautain et raffiné à la fois.

Answer (score 1):

Cette formule est fausse en langue française, il ne faut pas l'employer.

Answer (score 1):

"Messieurs-dames", c'est à bannir ABSOLUMENT du langage. C'est considéré on ne peut plus "plouc" dans l'aristocratie ou la haute bourgeoisie, chez les gens du "Bottin mondain". Dire une chose pareille dans un dîner mondain, par exemple, ne sera pas du meilleur effet, même si les personnes bien élevées feindront de n'avoir rien remarqué pour que vous ne vous sentiez jamais mal à l'aise. Parce que la vraie politesse est la gentillesse. Evitez pareillement "au plaisir" et a fortiori "au plaisir messieurs-dames" à moins qu'il ne s'agisse d'une plaisanterie.

Answer (score -2):

Peut-être n'est-ce que moi, mais je trouve cette forme vulgaire et peu distinguée, effectivement.

> Bonjour mesdames et messieurs

sonnerait mieux, mais suivant les contextes, serait peut-être trop formel.

> Mesdames, messieurs

me semble être un bon compromis.