# L'expression « Bonjour à toutes » est-elle correcte ?

Tags: expressions, salutations, genre-biologique

Les expressions « *Bonjour à tous*  » et « [*Bonjour à toutes et à tous*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/752/3220)  » s'utilisent pour s'adresser à un auditoire masculin et féminin.

Mais dans le cas où l'on s'adresse à un public entièrement féminin (par exemple au début d'un email adressé à des femmes), peut-on dire « **Bonjour à toutes** » ? Je ne crois pas avoir déjà entendu cette expression.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C'est tout à fait correct selon moi.

Comme expliqué dans la question: c'est l'équivalent de "**Bonjour à tous**" dans le cas précis où il n'y a que des femmes dans l'ensemble des personnes à qui on s'adresse. Le choix entre **tous/toutes** est généralement fait si il est évident que le groupe ne contient que des hommes/femmes (souvent lorsqu'on s'adresse à des petits groupes).

Si l'assemblée est un plus gros groupe ou qu'il n'est pas certain de la présence de femmes dans l'assemblée, il convient alors de rester sur l'utilisation de "**Bonjour à tous**" ou "**Bonjour à tous et à toutes**". Les deux sont similaires, mais la deuxième solution est plus appropriée (et est légèrement plus respectueuse/formelle) si l'on est face à un groupe tellement grand qu'il est presque certain qu'il contienne des femmes.

Comment: Je pense aussi que c'est correct. Plus simplement, la règle est que : "Le masculin l'emporte toujours".
Des qu'il est possible que le masculin soit présent (même si minoritaire) alors il faut le privilégier.

Comment: Pouvez-vous étayer cette réponse avec des références ou des sources SVP ?

Comment: Par galanterie (il en reste encore un peu), lorsque l'on utilise les deux genres, les dames viennent d'abord. Ce serait donc plutôt « _Bonjour à toutes et à tous_ ». Concernant les sources, la règle citée précédemment est juste et applicable à toutes les variantes : si au moins un homme _peut_ figurer parmi la liste, on utilise _tous_ (ou _toutes et tous_ si on tient à faire la distinction). Si on sait qu'il n'y a que des femmes, _toutes_ est juste.

Comment: Autre point de justification : « Bonjour à toutes et à tous » est une contraction de « Bonjour à toutes et bonjour à tous ». Si tu considères que cette tournure est correcte, c'est que chacune des deux séparément peut être considérée correcte indépendamment.

Comment: La question de savoir si citer séparément hommes et femmes est plus respectueux que de les regrouper en tant qu'êtres humain est plus correcte reste discutable. La dernière phrase reste un peu une question d'avis et de politiquement correct. Le reste est juste, sans aucun doute.

Answer (score 2):

On peut aussi utiliser l'expression "bonjour tout le monde" ou "bonjour mesdames"

Answer (score 2):

In French there is a rule that says : le masculin l'emporte.
It means that when there is only 1 boy, using 'toutes' won't be correct anymore, if you talk to 100 girls and 1 boy you can say 'Bonjour à tous' or 'Bonjour à toutes et à tous' but 'Bonjour à toutes' is not correct in this case.

An other example is the using of 'ils' 'elles' so if you talk to:
15 boys : 'ils'
15 girls : 'elles'
14 girl + 1 boy = 'ils'

I hope it will help anyone who need it.

Comment: this is hardly a improvement on Cédric's answer.

Comment: First of all my answer is in english so it will be easier to understand for non french speakers ;) Then I gave some examples that are the easiest to understand. If you disagree with it you can say it but don't say 'this is hardly a(n ??) improvement'. But yeah indeed his answer is right, that does not mean other answers can't be helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

La règle disant que "le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin" ne concerne **pas la politesse**, elle concerne **l'accord grammatical** entre par exemple une série de noms et un adjectif :

> les chattes de toto, ses chiennes est ses chiens sont jolis.

Vous comprendrez qu'il y avait un choix à faire pour accorder **joli**. Il fut de choisir le masculin. C'est arbitraire et historique.

Sinon, il faut dire :

> Bonjour mesdames et messieurs

honneur aux dames.
Et s'il n'y a que des dames :

> Bonjour mesdames

Comment: – « les chattes de toto, ses chiennes ET ses chiens sont jolis. », merci. Le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin au pluriel (en français, car en latin ou en grec l'accord avec le plus rapproché est préféré), mais rien n'empêche de saluer les dames d'abord, puis les hommes. En l'espèce, « Bonjour à toutes » n'a rien d'anormal pour une assemblée du beau sexe ; «  Bonjour à toutes et à tous » fleure bon le politiquement correct, dont l'abus est … émétique chez les gens intellectuellement honnêtes.

Answer (score -1):

Le plus simple reste "bonjour" tout court; le reste est superfétatoire !

Comment: Pour s'adresser à un auditoire, si on veut respecter les normes de la politesse un simple « bonjour » est tout à fait insuffisant. Bienvenue sur FL François Brasse, FL n'est pas un forum de discussion mais un site de questions/réponse. Ce que tu as écrit n'est pas une réponse, tout au plus un commentaire. Pour pouvoir faire des commentaires il faut avoird e la réputation. Lire le mode d’utilisation du site [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -2):

Le fait de dire "bonjour" à un groupe de personnes, un auditoire etc... implique qu'on s'adresse à chacun en particulier. C'est donc stupide de dire "bonjour à tous" et les variations qui s'en suivent.

De même, il est stupide de ponctuer une conversation avec quelqu'un en lui souhaitant "bonne journée" alors qu'on lui a dit "bonjour" auparavant. Bonjour = bonne journée, c'est pareil, kif-kif. En France, on adore les redondances.

Comment: Bienvenue. « implique qu'on s'adresse à chacun en particulier » Pouvez-vous expliquer pourquoi ? Le second paragraphe ne répond pas à la question, merci d'éviter les digressions.