# Formules de salutation avec ou sans séparation des genres ?

Tags: usage, oral, correspondance, écriture-inclusive

Un sujet plutôt classique avec pas mal de questions dans FSE (ex. [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12896/lexpression-bonjour-%C3%A0-toutes-est-elle-correcte)), mais n'étant pas un locuteur natif, je me pose toujours des questions sur la bonne approche. De nos jours, faut-il utiliser des formules comme :

> Bonjour/Bonsoir à chacune et à chacun.
>
> Bonjour/Bonsoir à toutes et à tous.
>
> Excellente soirée à toutes et à tous.

dans des messages, des discours, etc. ?

Ou peut-on encore employer des formes génériques comme (à savoir en employant ledit masculin générique) :

> Bonjour/Bonsoir à chacun.
>
> Bonjour/Bonsoir à tous.
>
> Excellente soirée à tous.

sans problème et conflit avec la [féminisation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A9minisation_en_fran%C3%A7ais)/[neutralisation](http://www.colloquehomophobie.org/2018/files/2018/02/Outils_fran%C3%A7ais_neutre_R%C3%A9alit%C3%A9s_et-d%C3%A9fis_non_binaires_et_queer.pdf) imminente de la langue française ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

« Bonjour/Bonsoir à chacun.» semble bizarre et [ne se dit pas](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Bonjour+%C3%A0+chacun%2CBonsoir+%C3%A0+chacun.&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=).

Les formules avec « tous »  et « toutes » semblent convenir mais apparemment on ne les trouve pas dans les livres. De toutes façon ces formules ont quelque chose de très familier qui ne peut pas en faire des formules utilisables n'importe où.

Comment: De très familier ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Il me semble, oui (ou juste familier) ; ça semble aller bien pour les copains au bar et la famille et quelques autres, pour les artistes des spectacles de variété et concerts de musique populaire  qui saluent leur audience aussi, mais c'est tout.

Comment: @LPH Une personne enseigne à la fac. Elle entre dans l'amphithéâtre. Elle souhaite saluer les étudiants. Comment doit-elle s'adresser à eux ?

Comment: Je ne me hasarderait pas à dire comment elle **doit**  le faire, je ne sais pas ; ce que je sais c'est qu'il faut que ça plaise et à cette personne et à l'audience ; ils existe de multiples possibilités ; vous me dites que l'atmosphère dans les dernières années d'étude est celle d'un certain copinage entre professeurs et étudiants, tous  se tutoyant sans problème ; dans de telles conditions qui sait si « Salut les copains ! » ne pourrait pas aller, plaire à tout un chacun ? Il est important il me semble qu'il n'y ait pas de clash de coutumes, un peu comme dans le langage et ses registres.

Comment: @LPH Merci encore pour le commentaire !

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour/Bonsoir à chacune et à chacun : particulièrement nul, heureusement jamais entendu, mais un journaliste plus crétin que les autres trouvera certainement cette formulation intéressante et l'emploiera …

Bonjour/Bonsoir à toutes et à tous : aaah, le politiquement correct cher à tous les démagogues … Bon, pourquoi pas; ça n'a rien de familier ou bien ce mot a changé de sens sans qu'on me prévienne – mais on m'a toujours dit que la démagogie était la mort de la démocratie.

Bonjour/Bonsoir à tous : à employer tant que ce faire n'envoie pas au goulag ?!

Quant à la « féminisation/neutralisation imminente de la langue française », il est possible que certains prennent leurs désirs pour des réalités, personnellement je pense qu'il vaut mieux que le chien remue la queue plutôt que la queue remue le chien, et que la langue de tous ne doit pas être torturée pour le contentement de quelques-uns. Qui habet aures audiendi, audiat.