# Présentation: diapo avec remerciements (nécessaire ou non)

Tags: france, culture, présentation, académique

Nowadays, there is an active discussion about why one should delete the "Thank you!" slide (and how to end appropriately his/her presentation).
See, for instance,

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/delete-thank-you-slide-how-end-your-presentation-brian-mccarthy/

https://www.slidecow.com/blog/never-use-thank-you-slide/

http://newinternetorder.com/2-slides-that-are-ruining-your-damn-powerpoint-presentation/

I have failed to find any French articles regarding this issue.

Obviously, one would thank his audience. The trend that I see outside France is to make this orally rather than include an additional slide. E.g. the last slide could include some concluding remarks and perspectives. Once finished, one could say thank you for your attention without including an extra slide with some fancy layout repeating the oral idea.

So my question is rather simple: Is it still considered necessary for French presentation customs to include a "Merci de votre attention" slide (diapo)? Is it considered impolite its lack?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about the French language.

Comment: Cette question est assez *awkward*. En fait, ça n'a jamais été dans la tradition française de remercier son audience. Que ce soit à la télé ou dans des présentations (il suffit de comparer les programmes télé pour s'en rendre compte). Si tu as rencontré cette pratique c'est surement récent et par assimilation de l'usage anglophone.

Comment: @user2357 Wouldn't you say the question concerns politeness in a certain context, just as the question got at through the following link? https://french.stackexchange.com/q/28921/17649

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Dimitris' question is specifically aimed at presentations and nothing else and it is a fact that practices in that domain have been largely dependent on anglo-saxon practices; the link I provide in my answer shows that the advice is to extend thanks  at the end of a presentation without fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [still people](https://www.spitchconsulting.com/agence-powerpoint/decouvrez-6-facons-de-conclure-une-presentation/) in the country who think the thanks slide is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously, one would thank his audience:-)! The trend that I see outside France is to make this orally rather than include an additional slide. E.g. the last slide could include some concluding remarks and  perspectives. Once finished, one could say thank you for your attention without including an extra slide with some fancy layout repeating the oral idea. Thus, I was wondering if this is considered something impolite in France.

Comment: @Dimitris I learned that new (and surprising) trend from your links; good to know.